# File Upload Error in Asp.net VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

I am trying to add a fileupload control to my aspx page so the user can add pictures, but when I am implementing the code behind on VB the fileuploader controler is not recognized.

I have this on aspx page inside a formview:

```
<InsertItemTemplate>   
    <div id="TaskScreenError">
        Upload a Screenshot of Error:
        <asp:FileUpload ID="ErrorScreen" runat="server"   />
    </div>
<InsertItemTemplate>
```

And I have the following code on my VB, but it says ErrorScreen is not declared.

```
Dim filereceived As String = ErrorScreen.PostedFile.FileName  
    ' validate the file to ensure it is an image
    Select Case Right(filereceived, 4)
        Case ".jpg", ".tif", ".bmp", ".gif"
        Case Else
            lblErrMsg.Text = "Image is in a format we don't accept, please use jpg, tif, bmp or gif."
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    ...
```

It might be something really stupid but I cant figure it out what is the problem.

Please help.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your FileUpload control is inside the InsertTemplate, you cannot access the FileUpload control directly. You have to do something like this:

```
Dim fileUpload As FileUpload = TryCast(YOURFORMVIEWID.FindControl("ErrorScreen"), FileUpload)
If fileUpload Is Nothing Then    
    ' Handle if the FileUpload can't be found
Else    
    Dim filereceived = fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName    
    ' Continue your code here...
End If
```